# About the expansion of \seq_set_split

Tags: latex3

As shown in fig, if I use the *keyval*, then my MWE does not work well.

[image]

What's wrong with my MWE?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{keyval}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}

\makeatletter
\def\BUPTthesiscntitlepage#1{\setkeys{cntitle}{#1}}
\define@key{cntitle}{title}{\long\def\BUPT@value@title{#1}}
\makeatother

\makeatletter\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_@@_title_seq
\NewDocumentCommand \settitle {m}
{ \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_@@_title_seq { \\ } {#1} }

\dim_new:N \l_@@_title_width_dim
\NewDocumentCommand \printtitle {}
{
    \group_begin:
    \@@_title_name_format:
    \tl_use:N \c_@@_title_name_tl
    \group_end:
    \group_begin:
    \@@_title_format:
    \@@_get_max_width:NN \l_@@_title_width_dim \l_@@_title_seq
    \dim_add:Nn \l_@@_title_width_dim { 10\p@ }
    \dim_log:N \l_@@_title_width_dim
    \parbox [t] { \l_@@_title_width_dim }
    {
        \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_@@_title_seq
        { \@@_underline:Nn \l_@@_title_width_dim {##1} \\ }
    }
    \group_end:
}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \@@_get_max_width:NN #1#2
{
    \group_begin:
    \dim_zero:N #1
    \bool_until_do:nn { \seq_if_empty_p:N #2 }
    {
        \seq_pop:NN #2 \l_tmpa_tl
        \exp_args:NNV \@@_get_width:Nn \l_tmpa_dim \l_tmpa_tl
        \dim_gset:Nn #1 { \dim_max:nn { \dim_use:N #1 } { \l_tmpa_dim } }
    }
    \group_end:
}
\cs_new_protected:Npn \@@_get_width:Nn #1#2
{
    \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box {#2}
    \dim_set:Nn #1 { \box_wd:N \l_tmpa_box }
}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \@@_underline:Nn #1#2
{ \underline { \hbox_to_wd:nn { \dim_use:N #1 } { \hss #2 \hss } } }

\tl_const:Nn \c_@@_title_name_tl    { Title: }
\cs_new:Npn  \@@_title_name_format: { \Large \bfseries }
\cs_new:Npn  \@@_title_format:      { \Large \bfseries }

\ExplSyntaxOff\makeatother

\BUPTthesiscntitlepage{%
    title = {AAAA \\ BBB\LaTeX B}}

\begin{document}
\settitle{AAAA \\ BBB\LaTeX BB}
\printtitle

\makeatletter
\long\def\BUPTtitletemp{\BUPT@value@title}
\makeatother

\settitle{\BUPTtitletemp}
\printtitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: `@@` is ***not*** to be used as a prefix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you set the title like `\settitle{\BUPTtitletemp}`, the `\BUPTtitletemp` macro is not expanded. So the splitting at `\\` fails. Expansion only happens when you actually typeset the lines in an `\hbox` (where you can't have a linebreak).

An easy fix in this case is to make sure the content that is passed to `\settitle` is at least expanded that far that an unexpandable token occurs at its start:

```
\exp_args_generate:n { Nnf }
\NewDocumentCommand \settitle {m}
{ \exp_args:NNnf \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_@@_title_seq { \\ } {#1} }
```

The result is as expected

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 5):

First and foremost: `@@` is an internal convention used in `.dtx` files to denote a common prefix in functions and variables and should ***not*** be used in production code.

The simplest ways to cope with your problem is to avoid `keyval` and use the more powerful features in `expl3`.

You can so store the title as a sequence, splitting it at `\\`, instead of having to do it later.

Also a `tabular` is easier than `\parbox`, as it doesn't require to measure the items.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\keys_define:nn { danger/BUPT }
 {
  title .code:n = { \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_danger_title_seq { \\ } { #1 } },
 }
\seq_new:N \l_danger_title_seq

\NewDocumentCommand{\BUPTthesiscntitlepage}{m}
 {
  \keys_set:nn { danger/BUPT } { #1 }
 }


\NewDocumentCommand \printtitle {}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \danger_title_name_format:
  \tl_use:N \c_danger_title_name_tl
  \c_space_tl
  \group_end:
  \group_begin:
  \danger_title_format:
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{} l @{}}
  \seq_map_function:NN \l_danger_title_seq \__danger_underline_endline:n 
  \end{tabular}
  \group_end:
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__danger_underline_endline:n #1
 {
  \underline { #1 } \\
 }

\tl_const:Nn \c_danger_title_name_tl    { Title: }
\cs_new_protected:Npn  \danger_title_name_format: { \Large \bfseries }
\cs_new_protected:Npn  \danger_title_format:      { \Large \bfseries }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\BUPTthesiscntitlepage{
  title = {AAAA \\ BBB\LaTeX B},
}

\begin{document}

\printtitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 4):

Note that `\settitle` is defined as

```
\seq_set_split:Nnn \l_@@_title_seq { \\ } {#1}
```

which meanse its argument should be *a set of tokens given in braces*. So

```
\settitle{AAAA \\ BBB\LaTeX BB}
```

will take `AAAA \\ BBB\LaTeX BB` as the argument, then split it at `\\` and push `AAAA`, `BBB\LaTeX BB` into `\l_@@_title_seq`.

However, when using

```
\settitle{\BUPTtitletemp}
```

the argument is just `\BUPTtitletemp` (NOT its value), which has no `\\` explicitly. Therefore, the whole title `AAAA \\ BBB\LaTeX B` will be pushed into `\l_@@_title_seq` as a single item. This will lead to errors since the following function such as `\@@_get_max_width:NN` does not allow `\\` in its argument.

Comment: Thanks for your help!